# What is the difference between AAB and XAPK？

Tags: android

In [What is XAPK file](https://apkpure.com/xapk.html) this website, they said "XAPK file = Base APK file + Split APKs file, The base and split configuration APKs contained in this APK bundle", it sounds similar to AAB(Android App Bundle) which is also split an apk into many smaller apks. so what is the difference between AAB and XAPK？

Answer (score 0):

App Bundle will build the APK that is targeted for a specific device and its configuration and resource requirements. This reduces the size of the APK. On the other hand, APK Extensions are used to serve additional feature data which is required by the APK. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery).